# Dynamically Resizing the Page

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I was always wondering how to make pages on the web more fluid and 100% responsive. So I decided to go about adding the following bits of jQuery pixie dust into my site's code.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
       $("div.content").css({
           minHeight : $(window).height() * 0.75
       });
});

// just to make sure it happens
$(function(){
       $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

Is this a good idea? Need some HTML5 gurus here.

Comment: There a reason why you have to use jQuery instead of css to achieve this? This could be done with media queries.

Comment: why are you setting the height and not the width of the pages? Any particular reason?

Comment: @Zoltan_Toth: Well, I only included the height here for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @chrisjlee: I used jQuery and CSS here, it's just that this is going to handle resizing of the window. The height of the window changes, but the size of the <BODY> tag doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to apply specific styles to certain window sizes then [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries) should do it.

Comment: It wasn't to specific window sizes, but rather to handle when someone un-maximizes a window or resizes it.

Answer (score 0):

media queries and percentages should do the trick.

Refer to my jsfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/qu6Za/

media queries makes it a responsive design and percentages makes it fluid within a single media query.